# Can I play YouTube videos at 2x Speed in DicePlayer or some other way?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

Before I commit to switching from iPhone to Android, I wanna make sure there's an app that can play YouTube videos 2x speed. On the iPhone, Swift Player can do it, and I read there's a way to do it on android by using youtube desktop version but I heard that DicePlayer from the Google Play store could do it. If anyone has DicePlayer, could you tell me if this is true? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was using DicePlayer and I confirm that it supports 2x speed for video playback for media contents.

I am not sure how are you going to play youtube videos on this player. Youtube uses it's own stuff to play the content.

Comment: can you see if there's a in-app browser that'll let you go to youtube and you can double speed the videos in that in-app browser please? thank you!